# Why is this code using both flatten() and reshape(1,-1)?

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, flatten

I have two questions:

1. Why has the programmer used both `reshape(1, -1)` and `flatten`? I think they do the same thing (convert rows to columns).
2. Is the role of `axis=0` to add the remaining  n-20 rows vertically to `X`?

```
k = 5  # supervising time (k next interval closing price that we are gonna predict)
N = np.size(data , axis=0)  # N = data.shape[0]
winSize = 20  # the size of sliding window
f = data.shape[1]  # the number of features
X = np.zeros((0, winSize * f))
Ytr = np.zeros((0, 1))
for i in tqdm(range(N-winSize-k)):
    X = np.concatenate((X, data[i: i+winSize].flatten().reshape(1,-1)), axis = 0)
    Ytr = np.concatenate((Ytr, label[i+winSize+k].reshape(-1, 1)), axis=0)
```

I have tried to use the code with only `reshape(1,-1)` or `flatten` but got error.

Comment: "I think they do the same thing (convert rows to columns).": you think incorrectly. Please try yourself (with a simple 2D array) and notice the difference.

Comment: But while `some_array.flatten()` is not equivalent to `some_array.reshape(1, -1)`, using `some_array.flatten().reshape(1, -1)` is near-nonsense. It does depend on the `data.ndim` whether it may make some sense, but we don't know `data.ndim`.